# What is the Shia perspective on Climate Change?

Tags: practical-islam, politics

The grand muftis of both Lebanon and Uganda supported the 2015 Islamic Declaration on Climate Change, saying:

> We particularly call on the well-off nations and oil producing states to lead the way in phasing out greenhouse gas emissions as early as possible and no later than the middle of the century.

Whereas the Declaration itself contained a strongly worded warning:

> Our species, though selected to be steward (*khalifah*) of the earth, has been the cause of such corruption and devastation on it that we are in danger of ending life as we know it on earth. This current rate of climate change cannot be sustained. And the earths fine equilibrium (*mizan*)
> may soon be lost.

However, Morocco was the only Middle Eastern country to present an emissions cutting climate pledge ahead of the summit, with the then environment minister, Hakima el-Haote saying:

> It is an emotive call for a spiritual fight against climate change that will be very important for Muslims ... It speaks to issues of accountability, fairness, differentiation and adapaptability on the Paris Agreement. I think the right way to make this call is through the Qu'ran.

Whilst, Ali al-Naimi, the Saudi oil minister said:

> In Saudia Arabia we recognise that eventually, one of these days, we are not going to need fossil fuels. I don't know when, maybe in 2040, 2050 or thereafter ... [and got this reason plan to become] a global power in solar and wind energy ... Solar could be more economic than oil

And that they planned to export electricity rather than oil.

Notably, in the main conference organised by the Islamic Declaration only a single religious scholar from Saudia Arabia attended, whilst none of the invited Shia religious leaders did so,

**Q. Given how much of the economy is dependent on oil, this might only have been expected of Saudia Arabia. Though of course one might equally and more justifiably argue exactly the opposite should hold. However, what underlines the complete lack of representation by the Shia clerics on this urgent global issue which affects the Islamic world just as much as the world elsewhere?**

**And has this changed since 2015?**

Answer (score 0):

According to Al-Monitor in 2015:

> Iran’s Supreme Leader Ayatollah Ali Khamenei issued a 15-point list of policy directives to address the country’s environmental needs. The Nov. 17 letter, titled “General Policies of the Environment,” was published on the leader’s website and addressed to President Hassan Rouhani, parliament Speaker Ali Larijani and head of judiciary Ayatollah Sadegh Larijani. General policies issued by the supreme leader often serve as guidelines for future policies, legislation and initiatives from the three branches of Iran’s government.

In the letter, Khamenei stressed the need:

> to manage climate change and environment threats such as desertification, especially dust pollution [and] drought.

And that this has been a concern in Iran since:

> A number of Iranian cities have been hit with crippling dust pollution this year. In February, public buildings in 11 cities in Khuzestan province were shut down because of dust pollution, with dust content reaching

Given the date, this can only have been prompted by the then Paris Agreement. Although this is not phrased as a *fatwa*, given that Ayatollah Khameini's standing as the pre-eminent religious leader in Iran - it may as well be.

More recently,  according to the Tasnim New Agency, the Ayatollah Khamenei in spring 2019 planted two sapings in Tehran to mark Tree Planting Day and stated:

> The issue of trees and protection of vegetation must reach its real position in the public culture.